# why is List<int> empty,even if I added values to it? c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq, empty-list

I have a question to which I basically know the answer.I would like to know why is newly created `List<int>` empty, how come it's empty even though I filled it with values? I could do it easily to create inside class `Vysvedceni(ReportCard)` list and then in Main class that I could create a separate field and then just add it to the `Dictionary<Enum,List<int>>` ...

Something like that:

```cs
List<Enum,List<int>> array = new ...
array.Add(1);
array.Add(2);
array.Add(5);
dic[Subject].Add(array);
```

**But I wanted to do it differently:**

```cs
Student student = new Student("Jan", "Novak",new Vysvedceni());
student.Vysvedceni.Znamky.Add(Vysvedceni.Subjects.math, new List<int>() {1,1,2,3,4,3});
```

My goal is simple, print Dictionary with Student and his/her marks.
My native language is not English, I wanted to translate the code, but I'm afraid I'll make a mess of it if you copy the code. At least I've added a small translation.
I've also added my comment where problem is or what methods do.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Cviceni1412
{
    class Student
    {
        private string jmeno; //Name
        private string prijmeni; //Surname
        private Vysvedceni vysvedceni;
        //Dictionary<List<Student>, List<Vysvedceni>> vysvedceniTridy = new Dictionary<List<Student>, List<Vysvedceni>>();
    
        List<Student> studenti = new List<Student>();

        public void SetridStudenty()
        {
            var setrid = (from student in studenti select student)
                .GroupBy(student => student.Jmeno.First()).ToList();
            foreach (var item in setrid)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "jmeno:"+jmeno + ",prijmeni:" + prijmeni;
        }
    
        public Student(string jmeno, string prijmeni, Vysvedceni vysvedceni)
        {
            this.jmeno = jmeno;
            this.prijmeni = prijmeni;
            this.vysvedceni = vysvedceni;
        }
    
        public string Jmeno { get => jmeno; set => jmeno = value; }
        public string Prijmeni { get => prijmeni; set => prijmeni = value; }
        internal Vysvedceni Vysvedceni { get => vysvedceni; set => vysvedceni = value; }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;

namespace Cviceni1412
{
    class Vysvedceni
    {
        private Dictionary<Enum, List<int>> znamky = new Dictionary<Enum, List<int>>();
        private Dictionary<Enum, int> vizo = new Dictionary<Enum, int>();
        private Predmety skolniPredmety;

        public Dictionary<Enum, List<int>> Znamky { get => znamky; set => znamky = value; }
        internal Predmety SkolniPredmety { get => skolniPredmety; set => skolniPredmety = value; }
        public Dictionary<Enum, int> Vizo{ get => vizo; set => vizo= value; }

        public double Prumer(Enum predmet) //Method for calulating Average and final mark for student
        {
            double prumerZnamka=Znamky[predmet].Average();
           
            return prumerZnamka ;
        }

        public void Vypis()//Print List method
        {
            Znamky.Select(i => $"{i.Key}:{i.Value}").ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        }

        public Vysvedceni()
        {
        }

        public enum Predmety//Subjects like math,Engl,P.E.,Physic
        {
            matematika,cestina,fyzika,programovani,telocvik,databaze,webovky
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
//Student class

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Cviceni1412
{
    class Student
    {
        private string jmeno;
        private string prijmeni;
        private Vysvedceni vysvedceni;
        //Dictionary<List<Student>, List<Vysvedceni>> vysvedceniTridy = new Dictionary<List<Student>, List<Vysvedceni>>();

        List<Student> studenti = new List<Student>();

        public void SetridStudenty()//Sort students to the group by their first letter
        {
            var setrid = (from student in studenti select student)
                .GroupBy(student => student.Jmeno.First()).ToList();
            foreach (var item in setrid)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "jmeno:"+jmeno + ",prijmeni:" + prijmeni;
        }

        public Student(string jmeno, string prijmeni, Vysvedceni vysvedceni)
        {
            this.jmeno = jmeno;
            this.prijmeni = prijmeni;
            this.vysvedceni = vysvedceni;
        }

        public string Jmeno { get => jmeno; set => jmeno = value; }
        public string Prijmeni { get => prijmeni; set => prijmeni = value; }
        internal Vysvedceni Vysvedceni { get => vysvedceni; set => vysvedceni = value; }
    }
}
```

```cs
//Main class
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Cviceni1412
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student student = new Student("Jan","Novák",new Vysvedceni());
            student.Vysvedceni.Znamky.Add(Vysvedceni.Predmety.matematika, new List<int>() {1,1,2,3,4,3 });//There is problem,List is declared and filled,but it prints just only Subject and [System.Generics...]

            Console.WriteLine(student.Vysvedceni.Znamky.Keys.Count);
            student.Vysvedceni.Vypis();  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `it prints just only Subject and [System.Generics...]`  Does it actually *say* that the count is 0, or are you just getting a class name where you expected contents?  The default implementation of `System.Object.ToString()` prints the class name....

Comment: Try `Znamky.Select(i => $"{i.Key}:[{string.Join(",", i.Value)}]")`

Comment: Don't use `Enum` as your key. Use the actual enum type you defined, `Predmety`. You're losing type safety this way. And although enums themselves are value types, `Enum` (the base class) is a reference type, so the enum values are being boxed when you use them anywhere that dictionary uses a key.

Comment: @BenVoigt it prints 1 for Keys and 1 for Values(count)

Answer (score 0):

**How I solved it.**
Problem wasn't with ToString() method,but with Print() method.Linq iterated just Keys.Hope I helped

```
public void Print(Subjects sub)
{
    foreach (var item in marks//dictionary)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
  
        foreach (var ite in marks[sub])
        {
             Console.WriteLine(ite);
        }
    }
}
```